# Stopping Node.js endless loop from on html button click

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

is it somehow possible to stop a long computation (in this example an endless loop) on a node.js webserver from HTML?

At the moment, I have two buttons (start and stop). The start button emits the function started on button click as follows:

```
function started(){
    socket.emit('started');
}
```

and on the server.js:

```
client.on('started',function(){
    while(!cancel)
    {
    }
});
```

How can I exit the loop from clicking the stop button?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you don't really show us enough code, but you probably can't do this.  node.js is single-threaded event driven system.  As long as you are in the middle of a `while` loop, you can't get any more events so you can't ever process anything that from the client that would change the `cancel` variable.

The only way this could work (though it's probably still undesirable coding on the server) is if your own server code inside the loop could change the `cancel` variable without getting any new events from the outside world to cause the loop to stop.

If you're relying on some other event to come into the server to change that flag, this could never work.  The whole design also appears to imply that a server is only serving the needs of one user which is also likely an improper design for a server.

---

This particular question as posted right now is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where you failed to explain your overall problem you're trying to solve, but instead described some issue you ran into in your particular attempted solution.  That prevents us from helping you with the real problem and, in this case, all we can really tell you is that this is a wrong solution and will not work.  Please don't post XY problems.  Tell us your real problem.  It's perfectly fine to show us your attempted solution and what issues you ran into with it, but only after you've explained the overall problem you're trying to solve.  That allows us to help you with higher level and better solutions that you haven't even thought of to ask about yet.

We could only help with a proper solution to your problem if you explained the actual top level problem and showed us a bunch more code.